# How to get value from a node in XML via SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I've found several pieces of information online about this but I can't get it working for the life of me.

This is the XML I have:

[image]

I need to extract the ID & Name value for each  node. There are a lot.

I tried to do this but it returns NULL:

```
select [xml].value('(/Alter/Object/ObjectDefinition/MeasureGroup/Partitions/Partition/ID)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
from test_xml
```

I understand the above would return only 1 record. My question is, how do I return all records?

Here's the XML text (stripped down version):

```
<Alter xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine" AllowCreate="true" ObjectExpansion="ExpandFull">
  <ObjectDefinition>
    <MeasureGroup xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <ID>ts_homevideo_sum_20140430_76091ba1-3a51-45bf-a767-f9f3de7eeabe</ID>
      <Name>table_1</Name>
      <StorageMode valuens="ddl200_200">InMemory</StorageMode>
      <ProcessingMode>Regular</ProcessingMode>
      <Partitions>
        <Partition>
          <ID>123</ID>
          <Name>2012</Name>
        </Partition>
        <Partition>
          <ID>456</ID>
          <Name>2013</Name>
        </Partition>
      </Partitions>
    </MeasureGroup>
  </ObjectDefinition>
</Alter>
```

Comment: This namespace stuff is something I am still trying to learn and understand, perhaps someone else can give an answer that works and explain it hopefully. If I find a way to make this work, I will post a new answer.

Comment: No worries. Thank you for trying!

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry I couldn't be of more help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL, XmlData XML)

INSERT INTO @MyTable (ID, XmlData)
VALUES (1, '<Alter xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine" AllowCreate="true" ObjectExpansion="ExpandFull">
  <ObjectDefinition>
    <MeasureGroup xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <ID>ts_homevideo_sum_20140430_76091ba1-3a51-45bf-a767-f9f3de7eeabe</ID>
      <Name>table_1</Name>
      <StorageMode valuens="ddl200_200">InMemory</StorageMode>
      <ProcessingMode>Regular</ProcessingMode>
      <Partitions>
        <Partition>
          <ID>123</ID>
          <Name>2012</Name>
        </Partition>
        <Partition>
          <ID>456</ID>
          <Name>2013</Name>
        </Partition>
      </Partitions>
    </MeasureGroup>
  </ObjectDefinition>
</Alter>')

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine')
SELECT 
    tbl.ID,
    MeasureGroupID = xc.value('(ID)[1]', 'varchar(200)'),
    MeasureGroupName = xc.value('(Name)[1]', 'varchar(200)'),
    PartitionID = xp.value('(ID)[1]', 'varchar(200)'),
    PartitionName = xp.value('(Name)[1]', 'varchar(200)')
FROM
    @MyTable tbl
CROSS APPLY
    tbl.XmlData.nodes('/Alter/ObjectDefinition/MeasureGroup') AS XT(XC)
CROSS APPLY
    XC.nodes('Partitions/Partition') AS XT2(XP)
WHERE   
    ID = 1
```

First of all, you must **respect** and include the **default XML namespace** defined in the root of your XML document.

Next, you need to do a nested call to `.nodes()` to get all `<MeasureGroup>` and all contained `<Partition>` nodes, so that you can reach into those XML fragments and extract the `ID` and `Name` from them.

This should then result in something like this as output:

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to understand this better myself, why do you not have to add this to the XMLNAMESPACES `xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`?? Is it because xsd is already declared?

Comment: Thank you, Marc_s! this did the trick. Although I had to remove the tbl.ID / ID = 1 part.

Comment: @marc_s are the nodes partitions and partition consider nested since MeasureGroup is an xml of its own? Is this why the CROSS APPLY is necessary?

Comment: @RyanWilson: the `xsd` namespace doesn't need to be added because it's **(a)** not the **default** namespace (the XML namespace *without* a prefix), and **(b)** it's not used anywhere

Comment: @RyanWilson: you need the `CROSS APPLY` to handle **multiple occurrences** of a particular node. I'm not sure if there could be multiple `<MeasureGroup>` elements - the sample doesn't show it, but with the `CROSS APPLY`, the code could also handle a XML with 4 or 5 `<MeasureGroup>` nodes

Comment: @marc_s Thank you for the explanation. I appreciate it. So, just so I am clear, if `<Partitions>` was for example `<xsd:Partitions>`, then we would have wanted to add that to the `XMLNAMESPACES` ?

Comment: @RyanWilson: yes

Comment: @marc_s Thank you. You helped me alot.